# SAPUI5: Adding a custom label to a StatusIndicator

Tags: sapui5

This feels like it should be really simple, but I for the life of me can't figure it out. I have a StatusIndicator in my application and wish to give it a non-numeric label based on its value. I believe that this should be possible, because the [fiori guidelines for status indicators](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/status-indicator/) have example screenshots showing this behaviour on the bottom of the page (ok, granted, they're still all numeric, but not labelled with percentages).

Referring to the [API Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.statusindicator.StatusIndicator%23controlProperties) shows that StatusIndicator possesses an aggregation "label" which takes a Text-control. So I tried to use that (XMLView excerpt, link to plunkr below):

```
<si:StatusIndicator value="70" showLabel="true">
  <si:ShapeGroup>
    <si:Circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" />
  </si:ShapeGroup>
  <si:propertyThresholds>
    <si:PropertyThreshold fillColor="Good" toValue="100"/>
    <si:PropertyThreshold fillColor="Error" toValue="50"/>
  </si:propertyThresholds>
  <si:label>
    <Text text="Hi there"/>
  </si:label>
</si:StatusIndicator>
```

([Example in plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I9c75IY9lRI7GQv6))

However, this doesn't work. From my application I know the Label is used in some way (a formatter-function for the text is called), but the displayed label remains "70%" in the above case, instead of the expected "Hi there". Using a numeric value here does not work either, so it appears not to be due to that.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Unfortunately I was not able to find anything on this, and the API documentation on the label aggregation is rather sparse to put it mildly.

Final notes:

- I already tried using 'showLabel="false"' (thinking, maybe it only uses the custom label if the default is turned off), but that just removes the label entirely (as expected).
- I'm sure I could make a custom control for this, but would prefer not to, if I don't have to.

---

tldr: Why is the label-aggregation for a StatusIndicator control (seemingly?) ignored, and how can I add a custom label to the StatusIndicator that is based on, but not equal to, the value property?

Comment: Maybe it is good enough for you if you combine Text and StatusIndicator in a VBox / FlexBox. The label-aggregation "ignore" your setLabel because itselfs set the label with the given value "overwrite" it. After it is rendered you could set the label via javascript with setLabel(). Or you could use Object Status there you can set a label. And for shure you could build your custom one :-)

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me that "label" isn't really intended to be part of the public API, as it's overwritten during rendering. Resetting it after rendering works and can easily enough be encapsulated in a custom control, so I guess that's what I'll be going with. Thanks!